# remove shadow from inside label

Tags: ios, swift

I am giving shadow to my uiview in the table view cell. But along with uiview it also showing shadow on the labels inside the uiview.

My code is given below:-

```
     var data:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(200, top, 150, 21))
     data.text = "Data"

        cell.cellview.layer.borderWidth = 0.3
        cell.cellview.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red: 180/255, green: 180/255, blue: 180/255, alpha: 1).CGColor
        cell.cellview.layer.masksToBounds = false
        cell.cellview.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
        cell.cellview.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0)
        cell.cellview.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
        cell.cellview.addSubview(data)
```

Here cellview is the uiview inside the table view cell and the label data is created inside the uiview.
But this code is also giving shadow to label. Please help me in removing shadow from the label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add shadow path. If you don't it is computed for you. It is performance consuming operation and result may not be what you want. It is always better to add shadow path.

Simple example: (use your own rect from view)

```
var rect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
var path = UIBezierPath(rect: rect);    
cell.cellview.layer.shadowPath = path.CGPath;
```